# AWS EC2 Failed to execute script docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I can run my app with `sudo docker-compose up`  but when I just do `docker-compose up` I get

```
$ docker-compose up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 80, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 189, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[48420] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

This is my Docker file

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./data.go .
COPY ./handlers.go .
COPY ./main.go .
COPY ./static /static
COPY ./ssl /ssl
COPY ./views /views
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build $(ls -1 *.go)
RUN useradd -u ubuntu
USER ubuntu
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["go", "run", "."]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non root user,you need to add the user to the docker group.

1- Create a docker group if not exists:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

2- Add your user to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker [non-root user]
```

3- Logout and login to refresh group membership.